# Apache Redirect based on directory match & Add another letter to the destination URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

So here’s what I’m trying to accomplish. I have this link, I want to 301 redirect:

Origin URL:

`https://www.example.com/**folder1**/page.aspx?fh_location=%2f%2fpackages%2fnl_BE%2fpr_earlybookable%3E%7b0%7d%2fpk_active%3d1%2fpk_siteswitch%3E%7bnvb%7d%2fpk_country%3E%7biso_pt%7d%2fpk_city%3E%7bgeo_9833%7d%2fpr_duration%3E%7b0608%7d%2fpk_hotelonly%3d0&fh_sort_by=pr_defaultprice&**fh_secondid=nbs_city_cli16a_s18**&fh_view=detail&fh_eds=%C3%9F&RoomOccupation1=CLI16A_2a_LO_2_0`

**Condition 1**: I have a list of Directories such as `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, `folder4`. I want to redirect only if the URL contains any of the folders listed above, but not for `folder5` or any other folders not listed above in the URL.

**Condition 2**: Now comes the tricky part; in the destination it should take the id `"cli16a"` from the URL `fh_secondid=nbs_city_cli16a_s18` and then append to the destination URL as seen below

`https://www.example.com/be/_CLI16A**Y**/`

**Condition 3**: Now the most tricky part. Add that "Y" to the destination URL, which represents the folder in the origin URL, eg., `folder1 = Y`, `folder2 = O`, `folder3 = B`, `folder4 = C`.

So far I have come up with the below.

```
**RewriteMap WE NEED TO GET A MAPPING OF TYPE OF HOTEL** (not sure what to put here)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ==(folder1|folder2|folder3|folder4) [NC]
RewriteCond ${conv-lc:%{QUERY_STRING}} (fh_secondid)=[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_
**RewriteRule ^/nl/_USE RewriteMap Matching text here/** ( not sure what to put here)
```

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: @scopchanov Thanks I have posted in server fault.